# If a sequence of function converges in $L^2$ sense, then its Fourier series converges in $l^2$ sense?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have the following material from my lecture notes and I am trying to prove it, but I am not sure how to do the second part.

> Suppose we have a sequence of continuous functions $\{q_n (x)\}$ defined on some interval, say $[-\pi,\pi]$. Suppose the sequence $\{q_n(x)\}$ is Cauchy in $L^2$ sense, meaning that
>
> $$\left(\int_{-\pi}^\pi |q_m (x) - q_n (x)|^2 dx\right)^\frac{1}{2} \longrightarrow 0 $$ as $m,n \longrightarrow \infty$. Then is it true that their Fourier coefficients form a Cauchy sequence in $l^2$?

Suppose $q_m(x)$ has Fourier coefficients $a_{m,0},a_{m,1},\dots\dots$. First we have to show that this sequence is actually in $l^2$. To this, I use the Parseval's identity $\|q_m\|^2 = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty |a_{m,n}|^2$ and the fact that $\|q_m\|$ doesn't blow up.

In order to show the points of sequence of Fourier coefficients are Cauchy in $l^2$ sense, we have to show that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that

$$m,n>N\Longrightarrow \left(\sum_{-\infty}^\infty |a_{m,i}-b_{n,i}|^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}<\epsilon$$

Pick an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, then we know that there exists $N$ such that

$$m,n>N \Longrightarrow \left(\int_\pi^\pi |q_m(x) - q_n(x)|^2 dx \right)^\frac{1}{2} < \epsilon$$

I attempt to write the integral in terms of the series, which gives me

$$\left(\int_{-\pi}^\pi |\sum (a_{m,i} - a_{n,i})e^{-inx}|^2 dx\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$

Since $e^{-inx}$ where ${n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ form an orthonormal basis, we further have

$$\left(\int_{-\pi}^\pi |\sum (a_{m,i} - a_{n,i})e^{-inx}|^2 dx\right)^\frac{1}{2}=\left(\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sum|a_{m,i}-a_{n,i}|^2 dx\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$

But then I am stucked at the last step (assuming what I have above has nothing wrong). I feel like what I have now is enough but somehow I am missing an inequality involving integral...

Comment: There is nothing wrong. It's just you missed a $1/2\pi$ factor in your definition of inner product on $L^2$.